# Is there any way to get a remote WebLogic path?

Tags: webserver

I know the IP address and the port number of a remote [WebLogic](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/overview/index-085209.html) web server, but cannot remember the path. How can I get the path of it?

And it doesn’t seem one can browse the directory of the WebLogic. So it is even possible to technically get that path?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the domain path then :

1) Check for the weblogic process running on the server

ps -ef|grep -i Admin

It will show you the Admin server process running then use

pwdx pid ;pid of admin server to get path on linux

This will give the absolute domain path

2) you can also use find command

find / -name "config.xml"

It will show use the config.xml path which is there in domain/config folder

By remotely you can use jmx to connect to weblogic domain

Comment: I don't have any username of that server.I can only connect to port 7001 which is the only open to me, others are closed.

Comment: Are you having weblogic console username and password ?If yes then you can check use console to do what ever required.If console is disabled then you can install weblogic on your local machine and by using wlst you can connect to domain and do necessary work.If you dont have weblogic username and password then it is quite difficult.But if you can get phyical user(os level user)  access of the weblogic you can use boot.properties and decrypt password of weblogic and use it :)

Comment: Your approch is great. My problem is the weblogic is yours and I just want to use your website.Your website is http://youripaddrea:7001/yourpath, I forget yourpath, can I get yourpath technically without asking you.

Comment: Oh..!Now i understand the thing.That's really difficult.It is necessary to know context root.Without this weblogic will give 404 error.Technically there is know legal way.This is not impossible there are others ways but those will be termed as hacking .You simply need to ask me your path and need to bookmark same .